# Conceptually creating a discriminated union for an appointment in F# from C#

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Be kind, I am a complete newbie to F# (coming from C#). In reviewing a user control for my appointment book, I see it is built upon the class concept of a "Visit" being used to fill a datagrid. I would like to use an F# descriminated union to replace the C# Visit class, but can't get it right. After much reading, I can't seem to break my thinking in C#.

Conceptually, a "Visit" will always have an "appointmentTime", regardless of it having a name or anything else. Now from this point a visit can be several different things (the reason for a using a discrimated union):

1. If the visit only has a name and posting time, then it is an appointment only.
2. if the visit only has a appointment time, time of service and a name, then the person was here without an appointment, and is a "walk-in",
3. if the visit has a name, appointment time, posting time, and service time, then it is an appointment which the person was seen -- "a kept appointment",
4. if the visit only has an appointment time without a name or anything else, then it is available for use --"an open time slot".

In C#, this is a simple class:

```
public class Visit
{
   DateTime? tservice {get; set;}
   DateTime? tappointment {get; set;}
   DateTime? tposted {get; set; }
   string lastname {get; set; }
   string firstname {get; set; }
   DateTime birthdate {get; set; }
}
```

How can this be conceptually written as a discriminated union in  F#? And how would I use match...with with it?

Any help or guidance is most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is similar to ChesterHusk's one, with some differences:

1. Since `appointmentTime` is always present, I believe it makes sense to move it outside DU. Therefore, `Visit` is a record consisting of `visitType` and `appointmentTime`.
2. In `this.Name` we use a feature of named DU which allows us to capture only the required fields. This form is better since it is invariant of the order or the number of fields.

```
open System

type VisitType = 
    | AppointmentOnly of name: string * postedTime: DateTime
    | WalkIn of name: string * serviceTime: DateTime
    | Kept of name: string * postedTime: DateTime * serviceTime: DateTime
    | Open

type Visit =
    { appointmentTime: DateTime
      visitType: VisitType }
with
    member this.Name =
        match this.visitType with
        | AppointmentOnly(name=name) | WalkIn(name=name) | Kept(name=name) -> Some name
        | Open -> None

let visit = { appointmentTime = DateTime.Now
              visitType = WalkIn(name="cool_name", serviceTime=DateTime.Now) }

printfn "%A" visit.Name
printfn "%A" visit.appointmentTime
```

Comment: Nice use of the named-destructuring :thumbsup: I didn't think it was worth it for a simple example, but it's good to show off multiple ways.

Comment: Thanks! It's just I remember how much of the pain all these matching were in F# 2.0 in even slightly complicated cases (essentially, you always have to have the full definition in mind), so I'm really excited about ability to deconstruct like this.

Comment: @Dmitry Umm... What means "DU"?

Comment: DU = Discriminated Uniion

Comment: @Dmitry I appreciate the ability to factor out unnecessary fields as the next part of my appointment book expands the Visit record into another much larger record read from the database. However, the same constraints will apply. I also appreciate the use of options since error control will also need to be used. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) an example of how this could be modeled as a union in F#.

The basic idea is that you've described each case, and I've just translated each case you dictated.  Each case only had the data allowed to it, so there aren't nullables that may or may not be filled in. On top of that, I've defined a helper member that can be accessed from any form of the DU to retrieve commonly-used data (like I imagine the person's name would be).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to make `Visit` a record of `appointmentTime` and `vititType`, where `visitType` is a DU.

Comment: I disagree, given the few fields. The different cases clearly model different states, completely capturing the data for each field.  This is very idiomatic for f#, which is quite different from C#/Java.  Flag/status-style enums are basically useless IMO.